# Working in combination of TabControl and DataGridView Control

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am not sure whether it is possible or not? need suggestion

I want to display filenames from 2 different folders into 2 different DataGridview controls that are placed in 2 tab pages of TabControl1. Here is the code that I have tried. By running this code, I can able to show the filenames from a folder onto DataGridView1 in Tabpage1 but not in DataGridView2 of tabpage2.

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    With DataGridView1
        .Columns.Add("Column 0", "TaskName")
        .AutoResizeColumns()
    End With
    With DataGridView2
        .Columns.Add("Column 0", "TaskName")
        .AutoResizeColumns()
    End With

    Dim rowint As Integer = 0
    Dim name As String
    Dim directoryInfo As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\Demo\Sample1")
    Dim fileInfo = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directoryInfo.ToString)
    For Each name In fileInfo

        DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
        Dim filename As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(name)
        DataGridView1.Item(0, rowint).Value = filename
        rowint = rowint + 1
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub TabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TabControl1.Click

    If (TabControl1.SelectedTab.Name.ToString) = "TabPage2" Then
        MessageBox.Show(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Name.ToString)
        Dim rowint As Integer = 0
        Dim name As String
        Dim directoryInfo As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\Demo\Sample2")
        Dim fileInfo = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directoryInfo.ToString)
        For Each name In fileInfo
            DataGridView2.Rows.Add()
            Dim filename As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(name)
            DataGridView1.Item(0, rowint).Value = filename
            rowint = rowint + 1
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is your code (line numbers for reference):

```
1) For Each name In fileInfo
2)   DataGridView2.Rows.Add()
3)   Dim filename As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(name)
4)   DataGridView1.Item(0, rowint).Value = filename
5)   rowint = rowint + 1
6) Next
```

Your error is coming from line 4, which is referencing the incorrect DataGridView control.  It should be:

```
4)   DataGridView2.Item(0, rowint).Value = filename
```

With your code, you need to clear out the DataGridView2 every time you click on your second tab or else your data grid starts to expand with extra empty rows.

Not sure it makes sense to have this code in the TabControl1 Click event-- you might want to move this code to your Load event like you are doing with the first data grid.

Comment: As you suggested I moved the whole code to Load event. But the problem is when i click on either tabpage1 or tabpage2,blank rows are adding to the grid. how to avoid adding these empty rows?

Comment: @Ram It sounds like you are still doing ".Rows.Add()" in your tabcontrol click event.

Comment: Could you please give me an idea to make the existing grid empty?

Comment: I don't know what your code looks like at the moment.  If you moved the code from the tabcontrol click event to the load event, what is happening in the tabcontrol click event now?  Need to see more code, otherwise, use DataGridView2.Rows.Clear()